# PLC Program Reference Software

Tags: plc

I have a bunch of old machines that use a very basic form of ladder logic. What I have at the moment is a printed copy of the ladder logic but it is horrible at referencing its child nodes so I spend a lot of time searching through the sheets trying to find what conditions need to be set at this point and so on.

What I was wondering is: Is there a program out there that I can input all the ladder logic into and use it as a digital copy that I can add notes to nodes and link child nodes to their set condition (if they have one that is). I guess a DB version of the paper code.

I tried using some of the programmers but that isn't what I want because It is not a program I want to compile and send to a PLC (couldn't even if I wanted to, its a closed system). I am probably explaining this all wrong I am not sure what to be asking for I know what I want but that is it. I don't want something to check a program or find errors just a linkable DB of the paper version I have.

thanks

Comment: What PLC brand/type are you using?

Comment: That is just it, it is on a Toshiba Injection Mold Machine, we have 5 here and although I know it will take forever to digitize I know it will save so much time in the long run not to mention headaches. It is 100% proprietary Toshiba themselves only have 2 programmers left in the whole company. (circa 1986)

Comment: I was wondering, because ages ago I developed PLC software and even then (end of the 80s) our programming software had a pretty decent cross reference generator on board.  If the code is really basic ladder, without too much " function blocks" [the Soapbox Snap](http://soapboxautomation.com/products/soapbox-snap/) open source ladder editor might be a tool you could use to document your code?

Comment: @fvu - This looks great man, thanks so much. You should add it as an answer though so that I can mark it. Since all I was looking for is a simple application to input the logic and add notes to. I have only used it a few minutes but it is way better than the other solutions I was seeing. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering, because ages ago I developed PLC software and even then (end of the 80s) our programming software had a pretty decent cross reference generator on board, so with access to whatever programming console your PLC vendor uses you can probably generate cross reference listings and annotated versions of the software.  But especially with older machines the quest for a programming console can be nearly impossible.

As a plan B option, but one that still beats " unstructured" digitizing, and if the code is really basic ladder, without too much " function blocks" as our PLC vendor calls them, the [Soapbox Snap open source ladder editor](http://soapboxautomation.com/products/soapbox-snap/) might be a tool you could use to document your code?  As it's open source written in a popular up to date language (C#) it can probably even be extended if the need arises.